# Where exactly should a programming and database question be asked?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

I have been thinking about it for these days as I am in a new project with databases. As I have quite the knowledge using Python, for example, this is no problem for me, but imagine someone that is learning Python, and learning [SQLite 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite).

This person is getting errors and even though debugging, can't find the solution to the problem, so the person does not really know if that question should be asked on **Stack Overflow** or in **DBA**.

To make myself a little bit clear: maybe the person does not know if he is getting an error while iterating a Python dict, or an error when trying to insert the values of this dict to the database. Having this case (**remember, this person is learning both technologies**), where should that question be asked?

Is it no problem to ask anywhere, and if asked to, move the question to the other site, without getting downvotes due to wrongly classifying the question to a site and not the other?

Comment: I think person should narrow down on their debugging as much as they can and if problem deemed fit for any of the relevant SE site can post on it. [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for SO.

Comment: Sounds good to me, but what if that person, by debugging, thinks it is a programming issue when it actually is a db issue? @AbhishekGurjar And thanks for commenting!

Comment: Then I suppose it's going to get closed and have to be reposted at the appropriate site?

Comment: @M.K It is kind of odd how come anyone be in so much dilemma, either you are sure, partially sure or not sure at all.

Comment: Yes, but that person might get downvotes before it's closed for posting a question in a site that is not right for that, and those downvotes are quite a negative feedback, dont you think? @ivarni

Comment: I do not think it is such a dilemma if you are learning both technologies! @AbhishekGurjar any first year college student, for example!

Comment: Are "sqlite3" questions even on-topic on DBA.SE?

Comment: It was just an example. Any kind of db technology that can go into DBA.SE (mysql, for example) @yivi . Thanks for adding the proper tags by the way!

Comment: "remember, this person is learning both technologies" -> in a classroom, ideally.

Comment: @M.K I don't think downvotes are negative feedback if you've ended up posting your question on the wrong site, no.

Comment: Okay, that sounds like a good answer to me then! Thanks! @yivi Post if as answer if you feel like it

Comment: I personally think they are, if no feedback apart from "this does not belong to this site" is given. @ivarni

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do not believe it's so difficult to decide  if your question is about programming (being it about Python or about SQL scripts) or about Database Administration.

DBA.SE is about DB **Administration** and advanced database topics. From their [on-topic page](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> If you have a question about...
>
> - Database Administration including configuration and backup / restore
> - Advanced Querying including window-functions, dynamic-sql, and query-performance
> - Data Modelling and database-design, including referential-integrity
> - Advanced Programming in built-in server-side languages including stored-procedures and triggers.
> - Data Warehousing and Business Intelligence including etl, reporting, and olap
>
> …then you're in the right place to ask your question!

This page even stops to say:

> but, dba.se is *not* the right place to ask questions about...
>
> - Client-side programming - ask on Stack Overflow
> - Basic SQL - ask on Stack Overflow

If this hypothetical person can't really determine on their own if their question is about one thing or the other, I believe more research is warranted. The onus about topicality is still on the asker.

Or they can just post a question and learn to live with the community's feedback. But that's not good for anyone, really. Doing the basic research to determine where they should post is the minimum we should expect.

That the user is still learning (like everybody else) or a student or anything like that it's not a concern. We do not judge users, we assess post quality and usefulness.

Comment: DBA is far more lenient than the SO. But I don't know, how would they react in such an obvious case.

Answer (score 6):

Just because a question is on-topic on another site, it doesn't automatically become off-topic on SO.

If you have a specific, technical question about databases/DBMS or database tools you can always ask on SO. There's no borderline question here - no matter if the problem is related to programming language, SQL, tools or the database, it would be on-topic on SO.

The DBA site might however allow you to ask about other things that would be off-topic on SO: big picture issues, backups, data hosting etc.